# What is the limit of

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can you calculate

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)^x?$$

In general, what would be the strategy to solving a limit problem with a power?

Comment: write it as an exponential...

Comment: $y^x=\exp(\log y)^x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left(1+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e^{x\ln\left(1+\sin \frac{1}{x}\right)}.$$

You have that for $x\to \infty $, $\sin \frac{1}{x}\sim \frac{1}{x}$, therefore

$$\lim_{x\to \infty }x\ln\left(1+\sin \frac{1}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{\ln\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}=1.$$

Moreover $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous at $x=1$, and thus

$$\lim_{x\to\infty }e^{x\ln\left(1+\sin \frac{1}{x}\right)}=e^1.$$

Comment: Why do you use the exponetial if you know that $\text{sin}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \sim \frac{1}{x}$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$? You just need to compute $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x}  \right)^x$.

Comment: good remark, I have think about it, but to pass by the exponential is the more common way to solve a problem like this and as the OP ask for the usual strategy, I decide to it it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Take a logarithm. Let $A$ be the limit. Then

\begin{align}
A &= \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)^x \\\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \,\,\exp\left(x\ln\left(1+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{y\to0} \,\,\exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1+\sin y\right)}{y}\right)\\\\
\end{align}

Using the [Taylor series for $\ln (1+z)$](http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf) with $z=\sin y$ we find that 
\begin{align}
A&=\,\,\lim_{y\to 0}\,\,\exp\left(\displaystyle\frac{\sin y - \frac{\sin^2 y}{2}+\frac{\sin^3 y}{3} -\frac{\sin^4 y}{4}+\cdots}{y}\right)\\
\end{align}

Remember that $$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y}=1 \qquad\,\, \text{and, }\forall \, n >1, \,n \in \mathbb{N}\text{,} \qquad \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin^n y}{ny}=0$$

So in the exponent we have $1$ plus an alternating sum of terms that go to zero, which gives

$$A=\lim_{y\to 0} \,\,\exp(1+0)=\boxed{e}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \left(1+\frac{1}{x} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)^x,$$ as $x \rightarrow  \infty$. Thus,
$$ \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = \lim \limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x =  e.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use Taylor expansion $\sin t=t (1+o(1))$ when $t\to 0$. Then
$\left(1+sin \frac{1}{x}\right)^x \sim \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\to e$.