# Limit of $\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{2x+1}\right)^{1/(x^2-1)}$ when $x\to1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{2x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}$$
I know that the two-sided limit of $\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ does not exist. I don't know what to do with $\frac{x^2+x+1}{2x+1}$ to get something else than $1^\infty$

Comment: Did you try to rewrite this as a function of $t=x-1$?

Comment: No, I'll try it now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the limit of](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099885/what-is-the-limit-of)

Comment: @TerrenceTown, why is it a duplicate? It's another limit.

Comment: @miko, If you cannot use Taylor series, you need to specify this in your question body. People take time to help you with some ideas and, only after their answers, you say that their methods cannot be used. This is not pleasant at all.

Comment: @miko You're no more interested in this?

Comment: @AlexSilva, I don't even know what is Taylor series so how can I possibly specify this in my question? I checked it and I will learn about it in a few months.
I know that I must not use L'hospital so I specified this.

Answer (score 3):

Use :
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}h(x)^{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\mathbb{e}^{g(x)\ln{h(x)}}$$

In your case, $\lim\limits_{x \to 1}g(x)\ln{h(x)}$ is pretty easy :

Using taylor series :
$$\ln h(x) = \frac{(x-1)}{3}+\frac{(x-1)^2}{18} + o((x-1)^2)$$

Then factor a bit :
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}g(x)\ln{h(x)}=\lim\limits_{x \to 1}\frac{x+5}{18(x+1)}=\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: Could you explain, if you downvote :?

Comment: I will undone my downvote if you show that $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 1}g(x) \text{ln}\hspace{1mm} h(x)$ is pretty easy.

Comment: Taylor series, and you find $\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: Ok, you should write that. "pretty easy" is meaningless.

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for someone doing the work for him. That's why I just wanted to give an "hint"

Comment: I know, but your answer should have useful information. You were so vague.

Comment: Well, OP was trying with just calculating both limits. Using exp was in my opinion, a quite useful information.

Comment: I think you wouldn't have downvotes if your answer was useful,. But,... it's your opinion!

Comment: You are probably right. Should I delete it then ?

Comment: Or just develop it a little more.

Comment: + 1 Now, it is a good answer. :)

Comment: @servabat, Thank you, but I need to do this without using Taylor series (without derivatives or integrals). 
So I need to calculate $lim_{x\to1}e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}ln(\frac{x^2+x+1}{2x+1})}$. And it leads me to $lim_{x\to1}\frac{ln(x^2+x+1)-ln(2x+1)}{(x+1)(x-1)}$.
I'm stuck again. ;(

Comment: Can you use equivalence? By the way Taylor series can be calculated without derivative (in my case, I didn't used derivative as calculating these derivative would be soooooo long) (even if of course, they depend on it)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider $$A=\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{2x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}$$ Taking logarithms $$\log(A)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}\log\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{2x+1}\right)$$ Now, consider the Taylor series built at $x=1$ $$\frac{x^2+x+1}{2x+1}=1+\frac{x-1}{3}+\frac{1}{9} (x-1)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$ and use the fact that, for small $y$, $$\log(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ Now, make $$y=\frac{x-1}{3}+\frac{1}{9} (x-1)^2$$ in order to get the expansion of $\log\left(\frac{x^2+x+1}{2x+1}\right)$ and simplify.

I am sure that you can take from here and conclude not only what is the limit but also how it is approached.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x-1$. Then we have $$\require{cancel}\lim_{y\to0}\left(\frac{y^2+3y+3}{y^2-(y+1)^2+4y+4}\right)^{\frac{1}{y(y+2)}}=\lim_{y\to0}\left(\frac{y^2+3y+3}{2y+3}\right)^{1/(2y)}=\\ \lim_{y\to0}\left(\frac{\cancel{y}(y+3+3/y)}{\cancel{y}(2+3/y)}\right)^{1/(2y)},$$ which, letting $z=1/y$, yields $$\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(\frac{3z+1/z+3}{3z+2}\right)^{z/2}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1+1/z}{3z+2}\right)^{z/2}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{3z+2}\right)^{z/2}.$$ Now we could do another substitution, but it is easy to see that $2$ next to $3z$ doesn't count when $z\to\infty$. Thus we can finally conclude the limit is $$\lim_{z\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{3z}\right)^{z/2}=e^{1/6}.$$